# Is there a trick to jumping higher?

Tags: superhot

I'm trying to reach the secret terminal in level 5 (Subway). I know where the terminal is, but I can't reach it.

[image: Screenshot depicting the final two benches]

All I need is to jump on two more benches, but I can't seem to jump high enough.

In games like Half-Life, I would crouch in mid-air, but I can't crouch in this game. Is there a trick to jumping higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, the bench jump in Level 5 is finicky.

There's no specific trick to jumping higher. I recommend jumping off the first bench as late as possible and aiming for the curved section on the right side of the second bench. It may take a few tries, but hopefully you should be able to get it before too long.

[image: Demonstration jumping between benches]

Answer (score 2):

Lock the framerate to 60 frames per second in the settings, it allows you to jump slightly higher for some reason.